# «stream cipher» — «потоковый шифр» или «поточный»?

Tags: прилагательные, словообразование

I would probably translate «stream cipher» as «потоковый шифр», от слова «поток», но на wikipedia статья почему-то называется [«поточный шифр»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80), хотя в содержании часто встречается словосочетание «потоковые шифры».

What's the deal here?

As far as Google goes:

- потоковый шифр — 167.000
- поточный шифр — 53.800

However, an exact search is exactly the opposite:

- "поточный шифр" — 26.000
- "потоковый шифр" — 11.600

Comment: Two adjectives can be formed from the word `поток`, `потоковый` and `поточный`, both of them are correct, use any of them.

Comment: @YellowSky, well, it is not the simple, it worth to mention that, while "потоковый/поточный шифр" are interchangeable, phrases like "потоковое видео", "потоковое вещание" are used tenfold more frequent that "поточное" forms.

Comment: @shabunc - To make it simpler, I must say that nobody spoke about what adjectives can be used with "видео" and "вещание", before you did it.

Comment: @YellowSky all I'm trying to say is that "потоковое" and "поточное" are not equally and interchangeably used in general, but it depends on exact phrase. I do believe this is good to know and relevant to the question in form of comment.

Comment: @shabunc - But that's OK, I just meant that the two words can be used interchangeably when speaking about cryptography.

Answer (score 5):

I've checked several Russian crypto books, they use both, sometimes within the same chapter. There is no discernible difference.

Answer (score 3):

There was a word `поточный` in the past (`поточное производство`, `поточная линия`): see [slovari.yandex.ru](http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/). And there was no word `потоковый`, it is a neologism, but quite popular. See [this distribution](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/ngram.xml?mode=main&t1=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&t2=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5&start=1940&end=2013&smoothing=3#toggle) from RusCorpora.

I would force using older form, but it's up to you.